# Could not convert string to float. Odoo 14

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I added a field with float type in 'purchase.order.line' , I would concatinate field price_subtotal and currency symbol in float field , but I got error when converting :

```
 raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '4.0€'
```

Here is my code :

```
 class PurchaseOrderLine(models.Model):
        _inherit = "purchase.order.line"
    
        price2 = fields.Float(compute='price_subtotal', store=True, digits=(16, 4))
        company_currency_id = fields.Many2one('res.currency', related='company_id.currency_id')
    
        @api.depends('price_subtotal')
        def price_subtotal(self):
            for line in self:
                line.price2 = float(str(line.price_subtotal) + self.company_currency_id.symbol)

    <xpath expr='//tree/field[@name="price_subtotal"]' position="after">
        <field name="price2" />
    </xpath>
```

What's wrong please?

Comment: Remove the `€` before converting to float.

Comment: line.price2 = float(str(line.price_subtotal) )+ self.company_currency_id.symbol  ? @Jacques

Comment: Exactly. You're converting the entire string into a float before initially converting just the number. Should be: `float(str(line.price_subtotal)) + self.company_currency_id.symbol` rather than converting to a float with the `€` included...

Comment: I got this error when trying this ,    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'   @Jacques

Answer (score 1):

```py
line.price2 = float(str(line.price_subtotal) + self.company_currency_id.symbol)
```

You're converting the entire string (with `"€"` included) into a float, causing an error.

Instead, you should first convert the number into a float before adding on the `"€"`.

Either way, you're going to want `line.price_subtotal` to be a `str` not a `float` when you want to add a string (`"€"`) onto it.

A better approach would to first convert the price into a float and then when printing include the `"€"`:

```py
price = float(str(line.price_subtotal))
print(f"Price:€{price}")
```

This would allow you to do calculations with the price rather than always having the `"€"` (making it a string) along with it.